# Does there exist an analytic function whose inverse has a disconnected Riemann surface?

Tags: complex-analysis

Looking at Wikipedia, I see the Riemann surface for the log, square root, and other multi-valued functions are all connected and are constructed via the inverse of an analytic function.

It seems like connectivity is a necessity, but I can't figure out why or if it's even true.

Comment: Riemann Surfaces are smooth manifolds, and are thus path connected and thus connected. Note they are rarely simply connected, e.g. the Riemann Surface for the logarithm (this is important, as this can be seen to be where *branches* come from)

Comment: ^ Smooth manifolds don't have to be connected by all definitions I have seen. But Riemann surfaces of analytic functions are connected by definition.

Comment: @JaneDoé Not all definitions of *manifold* require connectedness, but I am unfamiliar with a definition of *smooth manifold* that does not require it... you can't get very far with smooth manifolds without needing second countability and Hausdorffness, e.g. partitions of unity, Riemannian metrics, etc. Smoothness is a strong condition. Regardless, Riemann Surfaces are by definition complex manifolds and fall under the second countable + Hausdorff definition.

Comment: @JaneDoé What definition do you refer to?

Comment: I don't think it's standard to assume that even smooth ($C^\infty$) manifolds are connected. This is not necessary to define a smooth structure, so why assume it? For instance, this textbook does not assume it: http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/lee.pdf  . As for Riemann surfaces, the definition on wikipedia, for instance, requires that they be connected. And it makes sense intuitively if we think of patching together charts on which the function in question is single-valued. These charts will have overlaps are are path-connected, so the R.S. should also be connected.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I can image a manifold composed of two distinct sphere.  All transition maps are infinitely differentiable, but the spheres are disconnected.  Since the open sets of both spheres don't intersect each other, smoothness doesn't require there to be transition maps between them.